# fischerscode/flutter:stable docker image Permission issue

Tags: linux, debian, docker

[docker pull fischerscode/flutter:latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNrEv.jpg)

Not able to install, update and upgrade anything in image. only one user is there named flutter but the user not able to perform any action.

```
flutter@2854fb9986fb:/$ cd /root/
bash: cd: /root/: Permission denied
flutter@2854fb9986fb:/$
```

```
flutter@2854fb9986fb:/$ apt install clag
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How can I give full access to current user